# Apache RedirectMatch issue with relative path

Tags: apache, http-redirect, mod-alias

Recently, I upgraded my Apache server from 2.0 to 2.2.24, but I have an issue with `RedirectMatch`.

My old `RedirectMatch` directive:

```
RedirectMatch ^/abc/abcd  /otherurl/someaction
```

In Apache 2.0, if we use HTTPS to access, eg. `https://www.example.com/abc/abcd`, it will redirect to `https://www.example.com/otherurl/someaction`.

But in apache 2.2.24, it returns `http://www.example.com/otherurl/someaction` (HTTP, not HTTPS) - it seems Apache has changed the request schema.

If I check the HTTP response by http watch, I find a difference between 2.0 and 2.2.24.

Under Apache 2.0 the `Location` HTTP response header is `/otherurl/someaction` - a relative path URL.

But on Apache 2.2.24 the `Location` header is `http://www.example.com/otherurl/someaction` - the full absolute URL.

Any idea for this issue?

Comment: Could you add your entire configuration around `RedirectMatch`? If I understand your problem correct you miss the SSL part when redirect is made?

Comment: It could be that your `https` site is not enabled in Apache 2.2, thus making the `http` site the default one?

Comment: FWIW under Apache 2.0 an absolute target URL is strictly required, since Apache will not "fix" the target URL (ie. the value of the `Location` HTTP response header) to be absolute (this changed in Apache 2.2.6). If Apache does not make the target URL absolute then it is up to the user-agent to resolve the URL. In [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-135) (now superseded by [RFC 7321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) it was stated that the `Location` header must be absolute, hence why some "old" user-agents might not accept a relative URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that `Redirect` changed from 2.0 to 2.2(.6). And according to documentation:

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative
>       path is not allowed. The new URL should be an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and
>       hostname. In Apache HTTP Server 2.2.6 and later, a URL-path beginning with a slash may
>       also be used, in which case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.

I would suggest to change the rule to this **if** you just miss the `https` redirect:

```
RedirectMatch ^/abc/abcd https://www.example.com/otherurl/someaction
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks your comments, but the hostname is dynamic, it's based on request, in mod_alias, how can i get the ${HTTP_Host} in request??

Comment: How many hosts do we talk about? If it's just a couple you could hardcode them into different `VirtualHost` if you need it to be all dynamic you should consider using `mod_rewrite` and using a `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch`.

Comment: Agree, i think i have to change this rewrite rule by mod_rewrite. Again, Thanks your comments and suggestion.

Comment: As noted in the docs, "the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added" - so this should have worked unaltered on Apache 2.2.24. The problem is likely to have been caused by some other server config issue (eg. is SSL handled by Apache or a front-end proxy?).